# Adminhtml Form Button Value not Working

Tags: admin, adminhtml, grid, forms, adminform

I created a form in the adminhtml, all other fields are working well (ie., text, select, etc). However, I tried adding a button in the list of fields but it seems it's not picking up the value:

```
$fieldset->addField('test_button', 'button', array(
            'name'      => 'test_button',
            'value'     => 'Test Me',
            'label'     => 'Click the button to test',
));
```

Output is just:

```
<input id="test_button" name="test_button" value="" type="button">
```

Note that the value is empty, thus button is just a blank button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it now, instead of using `$form->setValues()`, I used `$form->addValues()` as the former overrides the value of the fields.

Answer (score 4):

If we want to show the provided value for the button than we have to change the function _prepareForm() used to load the admin form to use function addValues() instead of setValues().

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    //create form structure
    $this->_form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($this->_form);
    $this->model = Mage::registry('Namespace_Module');

    $this->_prepareRegularForm();

    //set form values
    $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData();

    if ($data) {
        $this->_form->addValues($data);
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(null);
    }
    elseif ($this->model) {
        //Using addValues() instead of setValues()
        $this->_form->addValues($this->model->getData());
    }

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```